# MariaDB (10.5.8) Galera cluster nodes have out-of-sync GTID if writes to not-replicated DB

Tags: mariadb, galera

I've configured a Galera cluster using [MariaDB official docker 10.5.8](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mariadb/library/mariadb/10.5.8/images/sha256-49f263b3e01dcefc7bad4fcebde09f64d523a6b1b349ca6b30d962a1d6832e2c?context=explore), consisting of 3 nodes.
At first, I could see consistent value of `gtid_binlog_pos` in all nodes. But after a while I needed a database that shouldn't be replicated, so I created a database `localA` and configured like `binlog_ignore_db = localA`. After that, whenever I write something to `localA`, nodeA's `gtid_binlog_pos` increased while those of nodeB and nodeC stayed same. My suspicion is that nodes maintain local sequence number, and they use it to independently create a their own GTID. Because local transaction is not propagated to other nodes, their seq no drift from each other.

Is this expected? Or have I missed something in the setting?

I'm trying to set up an async replica and want to be able to change master to any of Galera node, but this out-of-sync GTID is blocking me.

Below is the configuration of Galera nodes:
nodeA:

```
[mysqld]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
user = mysql                                                                                                                                                                                                
server_id = 11                                                                                                                                                                                              
port = 13306                                                                                                                                                                                                
default-time-zone = '+0:00'                                                                                                                                                                                 
autocommit=0                                                                                                                                                                                                
skip_name_resolve = ON                                                                                                                                                                                      
max_connections = 1000                                                                                                                                                                                      
max_connect_errors = 1000                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB                                                                                                                                                                    
binlog_format                   = ROW                                                                                                                                                                       
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log                                                                                                                                                                      
relay_log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log                                                                                                                                                              
log_slave_updates = on
binlog_cache_size = 32768
binlog_row_event_max_size = 8192
binlog_ignore_db = localA

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 2
innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm  = FCFS # MariaDB >10.1.19 and >10.2.3 only
innodb_rollback_on_timeout = 1
bind-address                    = 0.0.0.0

performance_schema = ON
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = ON
wsrep_log_conflicts = ON
general_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/mycustom.log'
log_output = 'FILE'

wsrep_on = ON
wsrep_provider                  = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_sst_method                = mariabackup
wsrep_gtid_mode                 = ON
wsrep_gtid_domain_id            = 9999
wsrep_cluster_name              = mycluster
wsrep_cluster_address =          gcomm://10.1.50.27:7567,10.1.52.27:7567,10.1.54.27:7567
wsrep_sst_auth                  = repl:secret
wsrep_node_address              = 10.1.50.27:7567
wsrep_provider_options          = "ist.recv_addr=10.1.50.27:7568;socket.ssl_cert=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-cert.pem;socket.ssl_key=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-key.pem;socket.ssl_ca=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-ca.pem;evs.keepalive_period=PT1S;evs.install_timeout=PT7.5S;evs.inactive_check_period=PT0.5S;evs.inactive_timeout=PT15S;evs.suspect_timeout=PT5S;gcs.max_packet_size=64500;evs.send_window=4;evs.user_send_window=2;gcs.fc_limit=16;gcache.size=128M;gcs.fc_factor=1"
wsrep_sst_receive_address       = 10.1.50.27:7444

gtid_domain_id                  = 9011 # should be different for all nodes and from wsrep_gtid_domain_id



ssl_cert                        = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-cert.pem
ssl_key                         = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-key.pem
ssl_ca                          = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-ca.pem

# File Key Management
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
# Enables table encryption, but allows unencrypted tables to be created
innodb_encrypt_tables = OFF
# Encrypt the Redo Log
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
# Binary Log Encryption
encrypt_binlog=ON
```

nodeB:

```
[mysqld]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
user = mysql                                                                                                                                                                                                
server_id = 12                                                                                                                                                                                              
port = 13306                                                                                                                                                                                                
default-time-zone = '+0:00'                                                                                                                                                                                 
autocommit=0                                                                                                                                                                                                
skip_name_resolve = ON                                                                                                                                                                                      
max_connections = 1000                                                                                                                                                                                      
max_connect_errors = 1000                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB                                                                                                                                                                    
binlog_format                   = ROW                                                                                                                                                                       
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log                                                                                                                                                                      
relay_log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log                                                                                                                                                              
log_slave_updates = on
binlog_cache_size = 32768
binlog_row_event_max_size = 8192
binlog_ignore_db = localA

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 2
innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm  = FCFS # MariaDB >10.1.19 and >10.2.3 only
innodb_rollback_on_timeout = 1
bind-address                    = 0.0.0.0

performance_schema = ON
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = ON
wsrep_log_conflicts = ON
general_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/mycustom.log'
log_output = 'FILE'

wsrep_on = ON
wsrep_provider                  = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_sst_method                = mariabackup
wsrep_gtid_mode                 = ON
wsrep_gtid_domain_id            = 9999
wsrep_cluster_name              = mycluster
wsrep_cluster_address =          gcomm://10.1.50.27:7567,10.1.52.27:7567,10.1.54.27:7567
wsrep_sst_auth                  = repl:secret
wsrep_node_address              = 10.1.52.27:7567
wsrep_provider_options          = "ist.recv_addr=10.1.52.27:7568;socket.ssl_cert=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-cert.pem;socket.ssl_key=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-key.pem;socket.ssl_ca=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-ca.pem;evs.keepalive_period=PT1S;evs.install_timeout=PT7.5S;evs.inactive_check_period=PT0.5S;evs.inactive_timeout=PT15S;evs.suspect_timeout=PT5S;gcs.max_packet_size=64500;evs.send_window=4;evs.user_send_window=2;gcs.fc_limit=16;gcache.size=128M;gcs.fc_factor=1"
wsrep_sst_receive_address       = 10.1.52.27:7444

gtid_domain_id                  = 9012 # should be different for all nodes and from wsrep_gtid_domain_id



ssl_cert                        = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-cert.pem
ssl_key                         = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-key.pem
ssl_ca                          = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-ca.pem

# File Key Management
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
# Enables table encryption, but allows unencrypted tables to be created
innodb_encrypt_tables = OFF
# Encrypt the Redo Log
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
# Binary Log Encryption
encrypt_binlog=ON
```

nodeC:

```
[mysqld]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
user = mysql                                                                                                                                                                                                
server_id = 13                                                                                                                                                                                              
port = 13306                                                                                                                                                                                                
default-time-zone = '+0:00'                                                                                                                                                                                 
autocommit=0                                                                                                                                                                                                
skip_name_resolve = ON                                                                                                                                                                                      
max_connections = 1000                                                                                                                                                                                      
max_connect_errors = 1000                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB                                                                                                                                                                    
binlog_format                   = ROW                                                                                                                                                                       
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log                                                                                                                                                                      
relay_log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log                                                                                                                                                              
log_slave_updates = on
binlog_cache_size = 32768
binlog_row_event_max_size = 8192
binlog_ignore_db = localA

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 2
innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm  = FCFS # MariaDB >10.1.19 and >10.2.3 only
innodb_rollback_on_timeout = 1
bind-address                    = 0.0.0.0

performance_schema = ON
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = ON
wsrep_log_conflicts = ON
general_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/mycustom.log'
log_output = 'FILE'

wsrep_on = ON
wsrep_provider                  = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_sst_method                = mariabackup
wsrep_gtid_mode                 = ON
wsrep_gtid_domain_id            = 9999
wsrep_cluster_name              = mycluster
wsrep_cluster_address =          gcomm://10.1.50.27:7567,10.1.52.27:7567,10.1.54.27:7567
wsrep_sst_auth                  = repl:secret
wsrep_node_address              = 10.1.54.27:7567
wsrep_provider_options          = "ist.recv_addr=10.1.54.27:7568;socket.ssl_cert=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-cert.pem;socket.ssl_key=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-key.pem;socket.ssl_ca=/etc/mysql/certificates/maria-ca.pem;evs.keepalive_period=PT1S;evs.install_timeout=PT7.5S;evs.inactive_check_period=PT0.5S;evs.inactive_timeout=PT15S;evs.suspect_timeout=PT5S;gcs.max_packet_size=64500;evs.send_window=4;evs.user_send_window=2;gcs.fc_limit=16;gcache.size=128M;gcs.fc_factor=1"
wsrep_sst_receive_address       = 10.1.54.27:7444

gtid_domain_id                  = 9013 # should be different for all nodes and from wsrep_gtid_domain_id



ssl_cert                        = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-cert.pem
ssl_key                         = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-server-key.pem
ssl_ca                          = /etc/mysql/certificates/maria-ca.pem

# File Key Management
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
# Enables table encryption, but allows unencrypted tables to be created
innodb_encrypt_tables = OFF
# Encrypt the Redo Log
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
# Binary Log Encryption
encrypt_binlog=ON
```